# Using large files in a OVHcloud AI notebook

Tags: python, data, jupyter, ai, cloud

I’m trying to train an artificial intelligence model on **OVHCloud AI Notebooks** with the Common Voice’s dataset from Mozilla.

The problem is that this database has a **70 GB size**. I have tried to download it on my computer, and then to export the database to the OVHCloud Object Storage so I can use it, but this is excessively long.

Is it possible to download directly this file on the notebook ? (My file is a **tar.gz** file)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can directly download this file in your **OVHcloud AI notebook** by running the following command in a cell of your notebook:

```
!curl -L "link-to-my-file" > my-file.tar.gz
```

Don't forget to put the `link-to-my-file` of your .tar.gz file in quotes.

2. If you want to store `my-file.tar.gz` in the **OVHcloud Object Storage** (from your notebook), don't forget to connect a volume (named `data` for example) with an object container to your notebook before starting it.

Use this command in a cell of your notebook:

```
!curl -L "link-to-my-file" > my-file.tar.gz /workspace/data
```

This way, you can have your `my-file.tar.gz` file stored in an object container in the Object Storage.